# Unable to install grunt on windows 8

Tags: gruntjs

Been trying to install `Grunt` on my laptop to try it out, I already had `Node`, so installed the `Grunt cli` which went ok and then ran the command **npm init** to create the **package.json** file, followed the necessary steps and also went well, however when I get to the point of installing dependencies, I get an error.

For instance am trying to install `Grunt` as a dependency, with the following command:

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
```

After running this command I get the following error:

> No README.md file found

If anyone knows what I am meant to do please let me know.

Comment: Is it really an error or just a warning?

Comment: didnt try on windows 8, but maybe just add README.md with some content to see if the error/warning goes away...

Comment: Sorry my bad, yeah it was a warning, not an error, which doesn't let me install it though, will try your suggestion